# how to check a node value throughout the xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have a map like this, i have to check if name'A' is there and name'E' is not present in this Map,then i have to do something. How to check through out the xml for the same node 'name' and whether some other values like 'X' is there or not.

```
<Map>
<Employee>
    <name>A</name>
    <id>1</id>
    <role>SE</role>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <name>B</name>
    <id>2</id>
    <role>SE</role>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <name>C</name>
    <id>3</id>
    <role>SE</role>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <name>D</name>
    <id>4</id>
    <role>SSE</role>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <name>E</name>
    <id>5</id>
    <role>SSE</role>
</Employee>
```

Comment: Can you post your XSLT?

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<xsl:template match="/">

<map>
<xsl:for-each select="Map/child::*"> 
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="(./name='A') and not(contains(./name='E'))">
  <xsl:value-of select="123"/>
 </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</map>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: like the above i am checking

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there's an employee named "A" by testing (from the context of the parent node) for:

```
test="Employee[name='A']"
```

For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Map">
    <result>
        <xsl:if test="Employee[name='A']">YES</xsl:if>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>YES</result>
```

when applied to a **test input** of:

```
<Map>
    <Employee>
        <name>X</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>A</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>B</name>
    </Employee>
</Map>
```

---

### EDIT:

> i have to test two conditions 1> name'A' is present and name'Z' is not
>   present

That's a trivial expansion:

```
test="Employee[name='A'] and not(Employee[name='Z'])"
```

Comment: i have to check for one more name which is not present.....A is present and z is not present through out all the Employee Node.

Comment: Do you mean in the same test?

Comment: yes, in one condition only i have to test two conditions
1> name'A' is present and name'Z' is not present in that xml

Comment: one more doubt...
if above that i will use <xsl:for-each select="Map/Employee">
if i will write the code here ...its not wworking
</xsl:for-each>

Comment: No, there's no doubt about that: it will not work. As I said, you need to perform this test from the context of `Map`, not from the context of (each) `Employee`.

Comment: ok,actually i am changing with in a existing xslt, so i have to do the changes according to their document.can you help me for that.

in any other way??

Comment: and this way i can check only one time condition....suppose for the second time i will check something else..for name'B'...by giving <xsl:when>...its not working

Comment: I am afraid you are not being clear. It seems that your real question is different from the one you asked. If so, either edit your original question or post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a way to match all `<Map>` nodes where there is an `<Employee>` node with a `<Name>` = 'A', *and also NO* `<Employee>` node with a `<Name>` = 'X'.

To do this with `apply-templates`, you just need a simple template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/Map[Employee/name = 'A' and not (Employee/name = 'X')]">
   <!-- Do whatever you want with the <Map> node here -->
</xsl:template>
```

If you're doing it as part of other logic, you can also use an `<xsl:for-each>` (or `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>`) like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Map[Employee/name = 'A' and not (Employee/name = 'X')]">
   <!-- Do whatever you want with the <Map> node here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you want to be able to specify arbitrary values, you can use `<xsl:call-template>`.  First, define your template:

```
<xsl:template name="DoSomething">
  <xsl:param name="includes" />
  <xsl:param name="does_not_include" />

  <xsl:if test="/Map[Employee/name = $includes and not (Employee/name = $does_not_include)]">
    <!-- Do whatever you want with the <Map> node here -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Then call your template:

```
<xsl:call-template name="DoSomething">
  <xsl:with-param name="includes" select="'A'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="does_not_include" select="'X'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```